# Stanford40 Dataset no such file or directory error

Tags: keras, deep-learning, dataset, conv-neural-network

I am working on the Stanford 40 dataset. I will perform a classification process on this data set with Deep Learning. I'm getting this error for an image. The code I wrote and the error I received are as follows.
Every time I run the code a different image gives an error.
-------------code--------
file_names=df['filename'].tolist()
selected_images=random.sample(file_names, 9)

for file_name in selected_images:
img=Image.open(file_name)
img.show()

----------error----
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'texting_message_169.jpg'